Is the difference between $\alpha$-Hölder constants of $f*\rho$ and $g*\rho$ controlled by $\|f-g\|_\infty$?
Let $\mathcal D_1$ be the set of bounded probability density functions on $\mathbb R^d$. This means $f \in \mathcal D_1$ if and only if $f$ is non-negative measurable such that $\int_{\mathbb R^d} f (x) \, \mathrm d x=1$ and $\|f\|_\infty < \infty$. We fix $\alpha \in (0, 1)$. For $f \in \mathcal D_1$, let $[f]_\alpha$ be the best $\alpha$-Hölder constant of $f$, i.e., $[f]_\alpha := \sup_{x \neq y} \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha}$.
Now we fix $\rho \in \mathcal D_1$ such that $[\rho]_\alpha < \infty$. We define a function $\sigma : \mathbb R^d \times \mathcal D_1 \to \mathbb R$ by
$$
\sigma (x, f) := (f*\rho) (x) := \int_{\mathbb R^d} f(x-y) \rho (y) \, \mathrm d y.
$$

Is there a constant $C>0$ such that $[\sigma (\cdot, f) - \sigma (\cdot, g)]_{\alpha} \le C \|f-g\|_\infty$ for all $f,g \in \mathcal D_1$?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Not really, because the estimate "sees" the $L^1$ norm rather than the $L^\infty$ one.
Notice first that $f\mapsto \sigma(\cdot,f)$ is linear, so you question amounts to asking whether $[\sigma(\cdot,f)]_\alpha\leq C\|f\|_\infty$. We have then, for $x,x'\in \mathbb R^d$,
\begin{multline*}
\left|\sigma(x,f)-\sigma(x',f)\right|
=
\left|\int f(x-y)\rho(y)dy -\int f(x'-y)\rho(y)dy\right|
=
\left|\int f(y)\rho(x-y)dy -\int f(y)\rho(x'-y)dy\right|
\\
\leq
\int |f(y)|.|\rho(x-y)-\rho(x'-y)|dy
\leq [\rho]_\alpha |x-x'|^{\alpha}\int |f(y)|dy,
\end{multline*}
and this shows that
$$
[\sigma(\cdot,f)]_\alpha\leq [\rho]_{\alpha}\|f\|_{L^1}
$$

It is very intuitive from your answer, but can we construct a counter-example in case of the sup norm?

Let me add some general hints. You want a bound $[f-g]_\alpha\le C\|f-g\|_\infty$ for all non-negative $f$ and $g$ in $L^1(\mathbb R^n)\cap L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ with $\int_{\mathbb R^n}fdx= \int_{\mathbb R^n}gdx=1$. Note that by homogeneity, if the inequality holds for $f$ and $g$, it also holds for all their multiples $tf$ and $tg$. So it is equivalent to ask for an inequality $[h*\rho]_\alpha\le C\|h\|_\infty$ for all $h$ in $L^1(\mathbb R^n)\cap L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ with zero-mean.
On the notation side: no need to introduce the map $\sigma$, since you aleady have  $\sigma(\cdot,f):=f*\rho$.

(sorry I initially misread the question)

I could not find a counter-example to $[h*\rho]\alpha\le C|h|\infty$. Could you provide more hints?

I’ll try and write one

I start thinking there could be none...
